# How can I Rank suppliers based on price?

Tags: ms-access

I need to select first two vendors with lowest price

```
       Vendor      Item       Price    
       x           133        1.22      
       y           133        2.01
       z           133        .99
```

query would return:

```
    Vendor      Item       Price    
      x           133        1.22               
      z           133        .99
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming you want to select it for multiple items at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 2 * from Vendors order by Price desc
```

Comment: Ahror, Thank you for your answer.   I need to ask for more help - I neglected to mention that there are multiple items and they need to be grouped by item and then select the lowest two prices.   Sorry for the oversight.  Thanks again!

Comment: why you need to group by Item?

Comment: I have approx 2500 sku's and 10 primary vendors.   I wish to select the top two vendors based on low price so that I can import them into other software we use at work that only has the ability to have two vendors for any given item.     Thank you for your response - I'm learning sql SLOWLY.   Have a great day!    Ken

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find your hints / answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84157/how-to-select-top-10-records-from-each-category) .

.. Assuming that what you want is 
group by each item and then from there, 
getting the top 2 cheapest price of each item
 and determine who the vendors are.

Comment: Thanks.   I'll check this out tonight.